# Auotdesk Forge Viewing ZIP file with reference Model browser did not shows loaded model names

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Zip file uploaded and viewed perfectly, but the model browser did not shows the model names which are currently loaded. So we are not able to distinguish between the loaded models, even not able to understand the elements belongs to which model.

is there any solution or idea to address the current scenario.

[image: it contain 2 models but it did not list the models]

it contain 2 models but it did not list the models

Comment: Is it the Revit model or something else? If it's Revit model, you can find related information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64672951/7745569

Comment: is it possible to bind the information in Model Browser