# Forge Viewer_New model browser_Linked rvt files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

Thank you all in advance for your help.

My problem is that in the model browser I can't see the elements organized by model. They are all seen together in no order. I have been able to load linked files via jobpayload with rootFilename. I have seen a lot of information about it but if someone has done it or has an idea of how to do it, I would greatly appreciate the help or start. All the best.

[image: Example]

Comment: Goal:
Model 1
 -category 1
  -Family
   -Type
    -Element
    -Element2
-category 2
  -Family
   -Type
    -Element 3
    -Element 4
…

Model 2
 -category 1
  -Family
   -Type
    -Element 5

Answer (score 0):

If the model is a composite Revit model translation, the host and linked RVT files are translated by a zip package, the model structure will be merged into a single tree, so it won't organize the tree structure by models.

However, we can tell which object is from the linked RVT. See the concept here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64672951

and here is a [code example](https://github.com/yiskang/au-2021-forge-lightning-talk-sample/blob/main/server/www/js/revit-link-relp.js) that I use this function to get their dbIds.

```js
async getRevitLinkedElementIds(rvtLinkExternalIds, model) {
    const modelKey = model.getModelKey();
    const externalIdMap = this.modelExternalIdMaps[modelKey];
    const entities = Object.entries(externalIdMap);
    const linkedElementIds = rvtLinkExternalIds.map(instanceId => {
        return entities.filter(entity => entity[0].includes(`${instanceId}/`)).map(entity => entity[1]);
    })
        .flat();

    return linkedElementIds;
}
```

I think you can make use of the `linkedElementIds`, and then call `model.getInstanceTree().getNodeParentId( dbId )` repeatedly until you get the root node id, so that you can get name of non-leaf nodes, e.g., Family Type, Family, and Category, to rebuild your own tree nodes using [jstree.js](https://www.jstree.com/). (Don't use non-leaf nodes' dbIds, since they are shared by the host and linked contents)

[image]
[image]

Afterward, you can build node data of the [jstree.js](https://www.jstree.com/) like this for each models (host and links) to expand the tree structure of my custom panel in the [code example](https://github.com/yiskang/au-2021-forge-lightning-talk-sample/blob/main/server/www/js/revit-link-relp.js).

```js
[
  { id1, externalId: -1, type: 'revit-category', text: 'Curtain Panels' },
  { id2, externalId: -1, type: 'revit-family', text: 'System Panel' },
  { id3, externalId: -1, type: 'revit-family-type', text: 'Glazed' },
  { id4, externalId: '03d1b04e-ba90-4a0e-8fe2-eca95236e26a/ab343b7e-3705-4b87-bacc-33c06a6cee1d-000ee82e', type: 'revit-elements', text: 'System Panel [976942]' }
]
```