# How to manage externalIdentifier from different source files?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I export COBie data from Revit using Interoperability Tools. The '**ExternalIdentifier**' for each component has a format like this:

> "e17b1880-bb96-49aa-86d4-ab22f9922151-000d92f1"

While for the facility: '**ExternalFacilityIdentifier**', it is like this:

> "32c5jt5y91uf6x2dgZS$wz"

And it is different for each source file.
I export the COBie data from several source files (e.g. ProjectX-ARCH.rvt, ProjectX-MEP.rvt, ProjectX-STR.rvt). And, I upload via api to the bucket and do the transformation job as one compress file indicating the main file that links the others.

When I select an element in the viewer I get the externalId, if the element is from the main file it works because the externalIdentifier is in the same format as the exported. But, when the element selected is from the other files, I get something like this:

> "204b5424-5da9-4d99-9ef2-341a4fa0ad17-0009bd87/e17b1880-bb96-49aa-86d4-ab22f9922151-000d92f1"

If I get the double GUID from the viewer I can cut it off and query my database for the second GUID. But to select/focus the element in the viewer, I only have the GUID of the element, I do not know what the first GUID is or from where comes. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first GUID `204b5424-5da9-4d99-9ef2-341a4fa0ad17-0009bd87` is the GUID of the linked Revit document's `instanceId`. We can see that in the AEC model data.

```js
// Get linked documents data 
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
const aecData = await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(model.getDocumentNode());
const rvtLinks = aecData.linkedDocuments;
```

[image]

Here are references for you:

- [How can i get the list of link files from a translated compressed/zip of revit file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661353/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-link-files-from-a-translated-compressed-zip-of-revit-f)
- https://youtu.be/nfHZLlWtQ-0?t=111
- https://github.com/yiskang/au-2021-forge-lightning-talk-sample/blob/main/server/www/js/revit-link-relp.js

Comment: Thanks @Eason-Kang . `viewer.getAllModels()` is giving me an empty array. My RVT compress models in the zip file are Revit 2020 (It should work, right?). I used `await doc.downloadAecModelData()` instead. 
When there is a linked model it is easy to concat or not the `instanceId`. When there are many, how do I know which instanceId concat to the element guid for getting the right combination?

Comment: I'm wrong, even with a single linked file, how do I know whether or not to concatenate the `instanceId` to it? What I can think of is to iterate querying until you get the right one.

Comment: Probably, you have multiple viewer instances, please check if you call `getAllModels()` from the correct viewer object/instance. We can check how many viewer instances are in your web app by entering `NOP_VIEWERS` in the dev console. In addition, please call `viewer.getAllModels()` after model loading is completed.

Comment: We can find the link name from the model property by the `instanceId`, but first we need to exchange `dbId` from the `instanceId`, which is the external id od the linked model, or so-called Revit unique id. Here is an example: https://github.com/yiskang/au-2021-forge-lightning-talk-sample/blob/main/server/www/js/revit-link-relp.js#L251

Comment: Thanks @eason-kang `getAllModels()` works after model loading is completed.

Maybe I don't understand. Why do I need the link name? I have the element's GUID in my database without `instanceId`. If I try to select/focus it in the viewer, I need the `instanceId/element-guid` to get the right `dbId`. My question is, how do I know which is the `instanceId` of a specific element's GUID?

Comment: If I have a) 10 linked models, and b) 100000 elements in my model, and I have to use 'getExternalIdMapping' to search for each `instanceId` which combination of `instanceId/element-guid` exists, and I have to find it out for c) 100 elements. This has a complexity of a x b x c. I tried this and it takes to many seconds.
It seems it's better to find out the `instanceId` of each linked file, and finally concatenate the `instanceId` to the GUID in the database taking into account which `instanceId` matches the linked file it comes from.