# Retrieve Hierarchy of Linked Documents in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am currently working with the Autodesk Viewer to present Revit files, specifically ones that contain links to other Revit documents which in turn may also contain linked documents.

I am able to retrieve a flat list of all linked documents (including nested ones) by using the follwing command:

```
(await NOP_VIEWER.model.getDocumentNode().getDocument().downloadAecModelData()).linkedDocuments
```

For our purposes, however, we also need the document hierarchy (which document is contained in which).

Example:
Document A contains the linked documents B and C. Whereby B also contains D.

We are currently only able to retrieve the links:

A - B

A - D

A - C

...but cannot differentiate that the documents come from different hierarchical levels

So far I have not been able to get any information about the hierarchy via the properties of the links ([How can i get the list of link files from a translated compressed/zip of revit file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661353/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-link-files-from-a-translated-compressed-zip-of-revit-f)), nor have I found a command that could contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one potential solution (although perhaps not the most efficient one):

Whenever the [Model Derivative](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/) service is not extracting the desired information from your designs (which may be the case here), you can use the [Design Automation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) service instead, and develop a simple, custom Revit API plugin that will extract the dependencies between individual linked documents.

Comment: Alternatively, if you'd be willing to share an example dataset with us via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially - we would not share the data with anyone outside of Autodesk), we'd be happy to see if there's perhaps a more straightforward way of extracting the dependency hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have written an email (request number: 18255) which contains a sample data set